# Couchbase Java SDK Bucket Connection Management

Tags: java, thread-safety, connection-pooling, couchbase

I understand that `Couchbasecluster` objects should shared among application components, in that the `Couchbasecluster` should connect when the application initialises, and should disconnect on application shutdown. Is the same true for `Bucket` objects?

In a web-based application, should I retain a reference to an open `Bucket` connection, and share that reference across threads, or should I initialise a new `Bucket` object, perform the operation, and close the `Bucket` object during every HTTP request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Couchbase's [docs](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/java-2.1/managing-connections.html) :

> Here are some very important things to keep in mind:
>
> Always create only one instance of a CouchbaseCluster and share it across threads (**same with buckets**).
>
> The SDK is thread-safe, so no additional synchronization is needed when interacting with the SDK.
>
> If different clusters need to be accessed, reuse the ClusterEnvironment (see Sharing Resources).

You can lazily create and keep all the bucket objects in HashMap in a singleton and your application threads can pick from it. If they don't find the required bucket they can create a new one and add to the Map for other threads to use.

In case your application is hosted on many servers and each of them connecting to same couchbase cluster, please release the bucket by closing it whenever your application is not serving request(shutting down or gone out of load balancer) so that connections for other applications are not occupied.